# How to turn the application made in corona sdk/ lua into .apk?

Tags: sdk, lua, apk, coronasdk

I'm done with my application which is written using lua, corona sdk, and now I want my friends to be able to download it how can I do that? 
How do I turn it into .apk?

Comment: Have you read their documentation? http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/androidBuild/index.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack overflow. before we help you - it's often good for us to know what you've tried yourself to figure out the problem. We don't want to go over the same ground as you. So why don't you let us know the things you've tried first?

Comment: Corona SDK should produce the .apk file for you when you build the app.  From the File menu select File->Build->Android and fill out the fields on the form.  You will select an output folder for the .apk to be written to.  When it completes, you will have your .apk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My method of doing it is using Dropbox. First make a Dropbox account. Then go into Corona simulator open the app and under file tab select build (you may have to download java developement kit in order to build). Fill in out the fields, and build. Then find the .apk file and put it into your Dropbox folder. Then share to your friends using Dropbox.

Hope this helps =)